# How to create the timetabling with div properly?

Tags: html, css

I want to create the timetabling as same as the following.

[image]

Here is my css code with div label.

```
<html>
<header>
<style type="text/css">
div.whole {
    padding: 200px 0 0 0;
    width:660px;
    margin:0 auto;
    align:center;}
p.h {width:660px;text-align:center;}
div{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0 0;
    padding 0 0 0 0;
    display:inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
    width:100px;}
</style>
</header>

<body>
<div class="whole">
<p class='h'>timetabling</p>

<div>
<div>time</div><div>mon</div><div>tue</div><div>wed</div><div>thu</div><div>fri</div>
</div>
<div>
<div>9:00</div><div>x1</div><div>x2</div><div>none</div><div>x3</div><div>x4</div>
</div>
<div>
<div>10:00</div><div>none</div><div>x3</div><div>x1</div><div>x3</div><div>x4</div>
</div>
<div>
<div>11:00</div><div>none</div><div>x3</div><div>x1</div><div>x3</div><div>x4</div>
</div>
<div>
<div>12:00</div><div>x1</div><div>x1</div><div>x4</div><div>x2</div><div>none</div>
</div>

<div>
<div>total</div><div>2</div><div>4</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>3</div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The displayed effect is as following:
[image]

There are two problems here:
1.`margin:0 auto;` can't make it be center.
2.The div elements is displayed vertically,how to make it displayed  horizontally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For solution 1:** To make working `margin:0 auto` give `display:block` to `div.whole`

**For solution 2:**: "*The div elements is displayed vertically how to make it displayed horizontal*"  give class to parent div of row. Here i give `class="parent"` and give `width: 100%;` will make it horizontally.

```css
div.whole {
    padding: 200px 0 0 0;
    width:660px;
    margin:0 auto;
    align:center;
    display:block; //Here
 }

p.h {width:660px;text-align:center;}

div{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0 0;
    padding 0 0 0 0;
    display:inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
    width:100px;}
    
    .parent {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="whole">
<p class='h'>timetabling</p>

<div class="parent">
<div>time</div><div>mon</div><div>tue</div><div>wed</div><div>thu</div><div>fri</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
<div>9:00</div><div>x1</div><div>x2</div><div>none</div><div>x3</div><div>x4</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
<div>10:00</div><div>none</div><div>x3</div><div>x1</div><div>x3</div><div>x4</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
<div>11:00</div><div>none</div><div>x3</div><div>x1</div><div>x3</div><div>x4</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
<div>12:00</div><div>x1</div><div>x1</div><div>x4</div><div>x2</div><div>none</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
<div>total</div><div>2</div><div>4</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>3</div>
</div>

</div>
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vok59w50/)**

Answer (score 1):

this is what you want and, this will work with any size. I used internal style shheet, if you want you can use external.change the values as you want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>


    <style type="text/css">
      .manicontainer{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        border:1px solid black;
      }

      div.rows{
        width: 100%;
        height:50px;
        border:1px solid red;
      }

      div.rows div{
        width:16.6%;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: helvetica;
        float: left;
        padding-top: 10px;
        font-size: 20px;

      }   

      div.rows div:first-Child{
        background-color: black;
        height: 40px;
        color: white;
      }   
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="text-align:center;font-family:helvetica;">Time Table</h1>
 <div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="rows">
        <div>time</div>
        <div>9.00</div>
        <div>10.00</div>
        <div>11.00</div>
        <div>12.00</div>
        <div>total</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rows">
        <div>mon</div>
        <div>x1</div>
        <div>none</div>
        <div>none</div>
        <div>x1</div>
        <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rows">
        <div>mon</div>
        <div>x1</div>
        <div>none</div>
        <div>none</div>
        <div>x1</div>
        <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rows">
        <div>mon</div>
        <div>x1</div>
        <div>none</div>
        <div>none</div>
        <div>x1</div>
        <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rows">
        <div>mon</div>
        <div>x1</div>
        <div>none</div>
        <div>none</div>
        <div>x1</div>
        <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rows">
        <div>mon</div>
        <div>x1</div>
        <div>none</div>
        <div>none</div>
        <div>x1</div>
        <div>2</div>
    </div>
 </div>  


</body>
</html>
```